# Writing a birthday letter to a friend

Tags: word-choice, words, politeness, greetings

Okay here is my dilemma, I am going to a write to a Japanese friend a birthday letter but I don't know how should I construct it;  I've tried to search around the net and I found both formal and informal letters.

Now the problem is that friend of mine happens to be my boss in my Job too which means in my case I don't know which kind of format should I use in writing the letter.

Do I use the formal style with 拝啓 opening remarks or just write my message to him instantly (without the opening and closing remarks) and how should I address him in he letter? should I use さま、さん？

Comment: How do you usually talk to him? Do you use keigo, -desu, -masu, ~~さん etc?

Comment: yes I use -san but most of the time we talk in English but I still address him using -san

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is perfectly fine to use -さん when writing the letter, since that's what you normally use anyway. If you often speak to him informally, then you can revert to that style of speech after the opening. I find [this](http://birthday-techo.com/jyousi-messeji/) to be a good example:

> 例えば・・○○さん、お誕生日おめでとうございます。の後に
>
> - また今度職場の皆でカラオケに行きましょう！○○さんのあまい歌声をまた聞かせてくださいね。
> - また今度○○さんおすすめのラーメン屋さんに連れていってください！
>
> といった雰囲気です。

Speaking from experience of writing to professors whom I'm on very friendly terms with. Hope it's not too late.